# Same app name with Different Bundle Id and different platform

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone

I have an **ipad** application with name "abc" available in the app store. I have developed the same application for **iPhone**. So Can I use the same name "abc" for my iPhone applcation also? Do you know apple will reject the iPhone app due to same name?

Thanks and Regards,
Roshil K

Comment: If the deployment info in the project configuration is set to iPad & iPhone then you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same name if the name is not copyright(Trade mark), means your app will not reject due to same name.

Guidelines for Using Apple Trademarks and Copyrights -> https://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html